# How can I properly document this generic function?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

```
/**
 * Wraps a styled component to supply default props
 * @template {T} - Component type
 * @template {TDefaults} - Default props
 * @param {T} component  - Our styled component object
 * @param {TDefaults} defaultProps - The object's default props
 * @returns the styled component with default props applied
 */
export function withDefault<T extends { defaultProps?: Partial<TDefaults> }, TDefaults>(component: T, defaultProps: TDefaults): T & { defaultProps: TDefaults } {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  component.defaultProps = defaultProps;
  // Cast to any necessary as we can't infer styled component type
  return component as any;
}
```

This returns these errors:

```
  5:0    warning  The type 'T' is undefined          jsdoc/no-undefined-types
  6:0    warning  The type 'TDefaults' is undefined  jsdoc/no-undefined-types
  9:41   warning  Missing JSDoc comment              jsdoc/require-jsdoc
  9:135  warning  Missing JSDoc comment              jsdoc/require-jsdoc
```

Comment: Are you on the latest version of the jsdoc plugin? See https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/issues/428

Comment: Yep, on the latest: `"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^22.1.0",`

Comment: I'm not using typescript personally, so I don't have a workspace set up to test your code sample. You have your `settings.jsdoc.mode` set to typescript as well?

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing Yep, i do.

Answer (score 0):

For JSDoc `@template`, the thing inside the braces `{...}` is the *constraint*, and the template variable name should be placed after the braces. So the [correct syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#template) should be:

```
/**
 * Wraps a styled component to supply default props
 * @template {{ defaultProps?: Partial<TDefaults> }} T - Component type
 * @template {any} TDefaults - Default props
 * @param {T} component  - Our styled component object
 * @param {TDefaults} defaultProps - The object's default props
 * @returns the styled component with default props applied
 */
export function withDefault<T extends { defaultProps?: Partial<TDefaults> }, TDefaults>(component: T, defaultProps: TDefaults): T & { defaultProps: TDefaults } {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
  component.defaultProps = defaultProps;
  // Cast to any necessary as we can't infer styled component type
  return component as any;
}
```

You also need to set the eslint option `settings.jsdoc.mode` to `typescript` according to [this doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc#mode) to suppress the error.

Comment: I still have the following errors: `The type 'T' is undefined`, `The type 'TDefaults' is undefined`, `Missing JSDoc comment.`

Comment: I found the reason, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc#mode

Comment: I've set the mode to Typescript

Comment: Then i have no idea. You can setup a reproducible env post it on github for ppl to check